# setState when fetch data that leads Render in loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The problem is when i create paginaion button, the render is running in loop.
As i call api from external that i can store all data in dataset. I know something went wrong but i am not able to solve it personally, so can any one suggest solutions to help improve? Thanks.

**SearchScreen.js**

```js
componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({isLoading: true},function(){
        this.fetchData(this.url)
      });
  }

  async fetchData(query, pageNo) {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(query);
      let responseText = await response.json(); 
      let json = await this.getData(responseText, pageNo);
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  async getData(responseText, pageNo){
    this.setState({      
      data: responseText.response.listings,
      isLoading: false,
      currentPage: pageNo,
      lastPage: responseText.response.total_pages
    });
  }

  PropertyList(arr, navigate) {
    return arr.map(function(property, i){
      return(
      <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} underlayColor='#99d9f4'
            key={i} onPress={() => navigate('PropertyView', {property: property})} >
        <View key={i} style={styles.rowContainer}>
            <Image style={styles.thumb} source={{ uri: property.img_url }} />
            <View  style={styles.textContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.price}>{property.price_formatted}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.title}
                    numberOfLines={2}>{property.title}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      );
    });
  } 

  SetPage = (pageNo) =>{
    this.url = this.GetChangedUrl(pageNo);
    this.fetchData(this.url, pageNo);
  }

  GetChangedUrl = (pageNo) =>{
    return this.url.replace(/(page=\d+&)/g, 'page='+pageNo+ '&');
  }

  _formArray = (pageNo) =>{
    if (pageNo == 1){
      return [pageNo, pageNo+1, pageNo+2];
    }else if (pageNo == this.lastPage){
      return [pageNo-2, pageNo-1, pageNo];
    }else{
      return [pageNo-1, pageNo, pageNo+1];
    }
  }

  _createPageButton = (currentPage) =>{
    var array = this._formArray(currentPage);
    var btnBody = array.map( (item, i) => {
      return (
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.pageButton} key={i} Onpress={this.SetPage(i)}>
          <Text style={styles.text} >{i + 1}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>    
      )
    });
    return btnBody;
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    this.url = params.url;

    let propertyList;
    if (this.state.isLoading){
      propertyList = (
          <ActivityIndicator size={108} style= {styles.indicator}/> 
      )
    }else{
      propertyList = (
        <View >
          <View >
            <ScrollView >
              {this.PropertyList(this.state.data, navigate)}
              <View style={styles.separator}/>
              <View style={styles.pageContainer}>
                {this._createPageButton(this.currentPage)}
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        </View>
       )
    }

    return (
      <View>
          {propertyList}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

[Whole Code](https://github.com/johnchan2016/projects/tree/master/RN) from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is caused by:

```
Onpress={this.SetPage(i)}
```

which should be changed to:

```
Onpress={() => this.SetPage(i)}
```

Your code calls `setPage` when rendering and passes to `onPress` the result of the call, causing change of page, and therefore a new load, on every render.

Comment: thanks for reply, but the api provider cannot get connected, so i donot know whether it is work, i will test later. Then, can u tell why need to change to  arrow function ES6 , as i have changed in `setPage` function

Comment: @johnchan there is no need to use arrow function. The difference is that you want to pass a function, not to call a function.